# Permission message while copying container images from one Bluemix registry to another

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools

I am trying to copy one of Bluemix registry , registry.ng.bluemix.net/XXXX/rhel:v5 to another i.e. registry.ng.bluemix.net/YYYY/rhel:v5

by using command , after logging into Bluemix account & space associated with XXXX

```
cf ic cpi registry.ng.bluemix.net/XXXX/rhel:v5 registry.ng.bluemix.net/YYYY/rhel:v5
```

Note, I have access to both the org, spaces.

Bluemix showing following message ...

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Error response from daemon: Build aborted with error: User does not have access to namespace 'YYYY' Build ID: 268-1502886177.269-12875
FAILED
Command failed
```

Please suggest, what could go wrong and is there a way to proceed forward ?

Answer (score 1):

The build service currently only supports building from and to the oldest namespace owned by the targeted organization. This includes copying images using `cf ic cpi`.

To achieve what you want, you'll need to pull the image to your workstation, tag it, then push it back to the registry with the new name:

```
bx login <account with access to both namespaces>
bx cr login
docker pull registry.ng.bluemix.net/XXXX/rhel:v5
docker tag registry.ng.bluemix.net/XXXX/rhel:v5 registry.ng.bluemix.net/YYYY/rhel:v5
docker push registry.ng.bluemix.net/YYYY/rhel:v5
# Optional: remove the images from your machine: docker rmi registry.ng.bluemix.net/XXXX/rhel:v5 registry.ng.bluemix.net/YYYY/rhel:v5
```

Comment: This is unfortunate that Bluemix has this limitation, but it is really desirable and useful to have.
What you suggested , that will need a separate VM to automate the overall image build process and interestingly we are talking about PaaS !!

Comment: If you need this functionality added to Bluemix, consider submitting the idea to the IBM Cloud Structured Ideas site at the following URL: https://ibmcloud.ideas.aha.io/